# Embed a play app as a subproject in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I want to embed Playframework as a subproject in sbt and be able to make it depends on others subprojects.
The reason is others subprojects are libraries to be run in various containers, one being play another possibly be spark.

I was able to make subprojects depends on one another via the dependsOn directive but this doesn't work for the subproject containing the play webapp.

The best I can do now is make the play webapp run with a dependency on a locally published artifact but this is not satisfying. Since I want subproject writers be aware of the fact a change breaks the webapp.

If I remove .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala) on the web subproject dependencies are resolved and everything compiles fine but I can't use the play sbt plugin actions in the webapp subproject, such as run. When I try sbt can't find a main class.

In short I would like to compile all subprojects from the root project, go in the web subproject to compile the aggregated projects at this level too and use run, universal:packageZipTarball actions on this subproject.

I am using play 2.3.10 and sbt 0.13.8

Thank you for your help,
Yohann.

Here is the Build.scala file at the root of the sbt project.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object RootBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
                                        .aggregate(sub1, sub2, web)
    lazy val sub1 = Project(id = "sub1", base = file("sub1"))

    lazy val sub2 = Project(id = "sub2", base = file("sub2")).dependsOn(sub1)

    lazy val web = Project(id = "web", base = file("web"))
                                .aggregate(sub1, sub2)
                                .dependsOn(sub1, sub2)
                                .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)

    resolvers += "Typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
}
```

Then the build.sbt file in the web folder.

```
name := "web"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ws,
    "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.2.5",
    compilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.0.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
)
```